# Get Android NDK crash reports with Unity 2019.3+

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, crashlytics

Since Unity 2019.3 the Android build process has changed and now the gradle project contains two modules - a unityLibrary module and launcher module.

I am having trouble uploading native symbols as I cannot apply the plugin to the unityLibrary module, and only works in the launcher. Is there a certain way I can achieve this?

When I run `uploadCrashlyticsSymbolFileRelease` task that is only present on the launcher module, I receive this error:

`Could not find the file generated by Google Services. Please check your Firebase project configuration`

The configuration file is in the unityLibrary module.

Is there any way to move the task to the unityLibrary module? If I move the crashlytics plugin to the `unityLibray` module the error changes into:

`Crashlytics was applied to a project without an Android plugin. Please make sure the Crashlytics plugin is applied after the appropriate Android plugin for your project.`

Answer (score 2):

The tricky bit is that Firebase is still compatible with versions of Unity that do not support gradle integration. Because of this, the build pipeline in Unity re-implements the [functionality of the google services plugin](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin) (namely generating the `values.xml` file).

I've personally put *some* effort into massaging the `mainTemplate.gradle` file to work with gradle plugin, but haven't gotten the NDK upload to work yet. Some notes that may help:

- The [External Dependency Manager for Unity (EDM4U)](https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver) will both update the `mainTemplate.gradle` file if available but will also process `google-services.json` and drop the output into `Assets/Plugins/Android`. You'll likely want to run it once to generate the dependencies, delete the values.xml, and then disable EDM4U to prevent it from regenerating that file.
- The Unity SDK is based on C++, and the `aar` archives that bind C#, C++, and Java are packaged into local maven repository in your `Assets` directory. This will make it hard to relocate your project after generating it (ie: try to do all your work Unity side if possible).
- Because you'd be short-circuiting Firebase's processing of `values.xml` to use the plugin, you'll need to make sure `google-services.json` actually makes it into your Android sourcetree. `Assets/StreamingAssets` might do this automatically but you may have to write a build script to copy it over.

Finally, the team is aware of the desire to debug NDK code in the Unity Crashlytics plugin. There aren't any public timelines available, but in lieu of a good answer opening an [issue on the quickstart](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues) or [posting to the mailing list might](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/firebase-talk) could be a good way to try to work through the process.